# Swift leaks when using generic closure function with Double

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I have a simple array that holds `generic functions`. If store some `listeners` in this `array` I have a strange problem with `leaks`. I can use it without any problem with `generic types` of any kind but `Optional Numeric types`. If I use `Double?` for example I have a `memory leak`. Also problem only occurs when I capture `unowned/weak self`. Can someone explain me why this leak appear and how to fix this?

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var observations = [(Double?) -> Void]()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        observations.append { [unowned self] (new) in
            print(self)
        }

        return true
    }

}
```

If I change `observations` to `[(String?) -> Void]()`, then there is no problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 48 bytes out of many megabytes isn’t worth worrying about. But if you really want to pursue this, file a bug at bugs.swift.org.

Comment: I know it's not a lot, but I would like to have this fixed anyway. I filled a bug at https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7777 . Thanks

Comment: I just noticed that this happens only on device (tested on iPhone 6s) - does not cause leak in the simulator.